# Making images with Laravel Image::make(), getting low quality grey lines

Tags: php, image, symfony, laravel, imagick

I am scraping images from our partner's website with laravel, here is the code:

```
protected function generateImages($image, $fullPath)
    {
        $thumbs = Attachment::getThumbs();
        $tmp = Image::make(file_get_contents($image))->encode('jpg', 40);
        foreach ($thumbs as $thumb => $data) {
            if ($data['method'] === 'fit') {
                $tmp->fit($data['width'], $data['height'], function ($constraint) {
//                    $constraint->upsize();
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                });
            } elseif ($data['method'] === 'resize') {
                $tmp->resize($data['width'], $data['height'], function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->upsize();
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                });
            }
            $tmp->save($fullPath . $data['path']);
        }
        $tmp->destroy();
    }
```

but it returns images with grey lines on the bottom.

UPDATE: 
example of image: [IMAGE LINK](http://s32.postimg.org/k80ipandx/image.jpg)

I tried to change ->encode('jpg', 40) to png/gif/jpeg, and tried quality of 30/50/100, but nothing..

Comment: Please show an example image.

Comment: Have you tried to increase the quality `encode('jpg', 75);`?

Comment: I tried to change encoe quality, it didn't work.

here is example of created image bottom: [link](http://s32.postimg.org/k80ipandx/image.jpg)

Comment: FWIW that grey line looks like a broken JPEG. Of course it may be the image that's being loaded in is broken (and your image library is doing the best it can with it) or the image you save out. What image library are you using? You might find you can load an image from a filename directly without using `file_get_contents` and passing these raw contents into `Image::make()`.

Comment: I tried GD and Imagick, and yes, I tried without file_get_contents(), just inserted image link inside make(). Still not working